# tar: compress only the contents of a folder

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I have to compress only the contents of the folder, not the folder with tar, there is any argument for that? I have search but I don't find anything.

Example:

```
 mainfolder/
     asd1
     asd2
     subfolder/
     ....
     asdN
```

In my tar I want this:

```
  asd.tar.gz/
     asd1
     asd2
     subfolder/
     ....
     asdN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CD to "mainfolder" then execute

```
tar cvfz /path/your.tgz ./*
```

Comment: I want to do this out of this folder, because I am using a python script

Comment: finally I did using os.chdir() (That is like cd in python) thanks. Here your first check here and welcome :)

Comment: Why don't you use a python tar library? This is the more sophisticated way instead of using a system call.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for something similar and coming up empty. Finally found a solution on my own I wanted to share.

1. Got into target folder: `cd FOLDER`
2. Archive contents or target folder and place archive in parent folder: `tar -cvf ../FOLDER.tgz *`
3. Go back to parent folder: `cd ..`

Or all at once (replace `FOLDER`):
`cd FOLDER && tar -cvf ../FOLDER.tgz * && cd ..`